# How to add an app tab

Tags: tabs, instagram

I am trying to add an Instagram tab to my page below my cover photo. However, when I click "manage tabs" the only ones that are options are Events and Notes. Does anyone know how I can add Instagram or any other tabs that do not already appear on the list? If not, do you know why those ones are not appearing?
 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an instagram tab via https://apps.facebook.com/instatab/